# Is there a word that captures the different moods and ways a word can be pronounced in?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, speech

I am looking for a way to categorize these different ways a given word can be said to convey completely different emotions in different contexts, and I feel like there is some proper term for it that I don't know about.

For instance, you could say "Hi" in a very sarcastic way to convey a sense of arrogance, you could say "Hi" in a lower voice through your teeth to convey anger and contempt, or you could say "Hi" in a joyous way to convey that you enjoy seeing someone, or you could say "Hi" in an earnest way to convey meeting someone new in a professional environment.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the word you are looking for is "tone", and more specifically "expressive tone".

Comment: Well tone in audio already means the relative pitch, that's the problem.